# Most pythonic way to toggle a variable between two values

Tags: python, string, conditional-statements

I have a variable, p, that is the output of a regular expression match and is guaranteed to be either 'true' or 'false' in any mixed case.  If 'true' I want it to be 'FALSE' and if 'false' I want it to be 'TRUE'.  The end result is always uppercase.

I have thought of the following four methods.  Which is the most pythonic or is there a better one?

```
p=['TRUE','FALSE'][eval(p.capitalize())]
p=(not eval(p.capitalize())).__repr__().upper()
p='FALSE' if eval(p.capitalize()) else 'TRUE'
p={'TRUE':'FALSE','FALSE':'TRUE'}[p.upper()]
```

Comment: If that would be only four options I woul choose last one.

Answer (score 6):

IMO, the most pythonic way isn't with `eval`, or with dunders, or using a 2-element list indexing, it's a simple if-else conditional (or ternary):

```
p = 'TRUE' if p.upper() == 'FALSE' else 'FALSE'
```

It doesn't use hacks or trickery, it is simple and (more importantly) readable.

Comment: It is very readable but quite long there are some shorter ways to do that.

Comment: @RobotMind if there's anything I've learned in the two years since I've started programming python, it's that shorter not necessarily equals better.

Comment: Well, 4, if you count school.

Comment: Sorry about all those comments, I am much more used to C, and Assembly. And all pythonic one line mentallity isn't intuitive to me yet.
One thing I learned in all my years of development you can't  be good if you wertr not bad 100 times in the past.

Answer (score 1):

The solution by @cs95 is the way to go, but here is (IMO) an acceptable (albeit less readable and arguably more complicated) alternative:

```
p = str(p.upper() == "FALSE").upper()
```

Comment: @RobotMind would you prefer `p = str(p.lower() == "false").upper()`? At least it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:How about

```py
p=str(p.lower()!="true").upper()
```

No loops, no if, no complex functions. Just change type functions. Short and simple ;)

Comment: This would actually have be `p=str(bool(p.lower()!="true")).upper()` thus making the bool superfluous and a poorer version of pault's answer. So.